# How to play sound on iOS in C++ (equivalent of OpenSL ES used in Android NDK)?

Tags: c++, ios, core-audio, opensl

In my iOS app, I want to be able to play a stereo sin wave, in C++.

The purpose of it is to be able to replicate on iOS what I did on Android using the Android NDK, where I play music using OpenSL ES. I also need to use C++, not only because all my code for my audio player on Android is made in C++, but also for performance sake.

I found out that there are many functionalities in CoreAudio, but I don't know where to start, since I'm not an expert on iOS.

So is there any equivalent of OpenSL ES on iOS, so I can play a sound wave in C++?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try [OpenAL](https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft), it supports iOS too through [Core Audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Audio).

Comment: OpenAL works on iOS indeed. But note that it has been deprecated for a long time already. Maybe Apple will remove its support in the near future, so not a good candidate for a new project.

Comment: @prapin Oh ok, thanks for your comment, I was currently watching OpenAL tutorials. So if OpenAL is deprecated, what should I use then?

Comment: Also, I don't need "spacial" audio, since it's for a music app, just a regular C++ audio player like OpenSL ES would be great